# Webpack require npm module dynamiclly by variable

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

I can't find a way to require NPM module dynamically by variable.

Here is a sample code what I'm trying to do, Everything works great expect import NPM module dynamically.

```
const firstModule = 'my-npm-module';
const secondModule = './MyReactComponent';

// NPM Module
import(firstModule).then(...); // Doesn't work
import('my-npm-module').then(...); // Works

// Local React Component
import(secondModule).then(...); // Works
import('./MyReactComponent').then(...); // Works
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#import-) on dynamic import:

> Fully dynamic statements, such as import(foo), will fail because
>   webpack requires at least some file location information. This is
>   because foo could potentially be any path to any file in your system
>   or project. The import() must contain at least some information about
>   where the module is located, so bundling can be limited to a specific
>   directory or set of files.

Your best option would probably be to either not use dynamic loading for anything in `node_modules`, or add the explicit path to the module, e.g.

```
import(`./node_modules/${firstModule}/index.js`);
```